# Is there an implication of control/governance in Romans 8:6?

Tags: translation-philosophy, romans, niv

Romans 8:6 in the NIV:

> The mind governed by the flesh is death, but the mind governed by the Spirit is life and peace.

The word translated here as "mind governed by" is the word "phronema" which Strong's dictionary defines as "what one has in the mind; the thoughts and purposes". I'm struggling to see the sense of "governed" here. To me, it would just mean that if you have thoughts of the flesh in your mind that leads to death, but if you have thoughts of the Spirit in your mind then that leads to life and peace - without feeling that anything is governing you.

The more dynamic translations seem to retain this sense of "governance" or even control:

> "So letting your sinful nature control your mind leads to death. But letting the Spirit control your mind leads to life and peace." (NLT)

> "If our minds are ruled by our desires, we will die. But if our minds are ruled by the Spirit, we will have life and peace." (CEV)

My question is: Where does this sense of governance / control come from, and is it really implied by the original text?

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no verb in the Greek equivalent to "governed".  The Greek of Rom 6:6 reads literally:

> For the mind of the flesh [is] death; but the mind of the Spirit [is]
> life and peace.

Adding the word "governed" is an attempt to make good English as the original Greek has no verb at all!

Rom 8:6 is part of Paul's oft-repeated message about the imitation of Christ by setting the mind on spiritual things and things concerning Christ.  Here is a sample:

- Phil 2:4, 5, Each of you should look not only to your own interests, but also to the interests of others. Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ Jesus:
- Heb 12:2, 3, Let us fix our eyes on Jesus, the author and perfecter of our faith, who for the joy set before Him endured the cross, scorning its shame, and sat down at the right hand of the throne of God. Consider Him who endured such hostility from sinners, so that you will not grow weary and lose heart.
- 1 Cor 2:16, “For who has known the mind of the Lord, so as to instruct Him?” But we have the mind of Christ.
- Col 3:1-4, Therefore, since you have been raised with Christ, strive for the things above, where Christ is seated at the right hand of God. Set your minds on things above, not on earthly things. For you died, and your life is now hidden with Christ in God. When Christ, who is your life, appears, then you also will appear with Him in glory.
- 2 Cor 3:18, And we, who with unveiled faces all reflect the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into His image with intensifying glory, which comes from the Lord, who is the Spirit.
- Rom 13:14, Instead, clothe yourselves with the Lord Jesus Christ, and make no provision for the desires of the flesh.
- John 17:17, Sanctify them by the truth; Your word is truth.

See also Matt 6:19-33, Matt 12:33-35, etc.